Possible error in a paper about minimal sufficient statistic and minimal sufficient $\sigma$-algebra
According to Theorem 1 of [1], the stastistic $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is minimal sufficient for the statistical model $X_1,\cdots,X_n\sim N(\theta,1)$ iid and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. This is false, as you can see in the question: Function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ a.e..
However, this paper was written by a reputable author and that theorem is also corroborated by Theorem 1 and 4 of [2] and [3], respectively.
Before reading those papers in order to find an error, I want to confirm that I'm applying those theorems correctly.
According to the Theorem 1 of [1] we have:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^\times$ and $\{P_\theta:\mathcal{A}_\theta \to
 \mathbb{R}\}_{\theta\in \Theta}$ be a family of perfect
probability measures admitting a countable generated sufficient
$\sigma$-algebra. If $T$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for that
family, then $S$ given by $S(x_1,\cdots,x_n):=(T(x_1),\cdots,T(x_n))$
is a minimal sufficient statistic for the product family $\{\bigotimes_{i=1}^n P_\theta:\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \mathcal{A}_\theta \to \mathbb{R}\}_{\theta\in \Theta} $

For all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ let $P_\theta:\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the probability measure induced by the density $f_\theta (x):=(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2}}$ (normal distribution).
Using the Neyman-Fisher Factorization Theorem we can prove that $T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $T(x):=x$ is a sufficient statistic w.r.t. $\{P_\theta:\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}$. Since $\sigma(T)$ is countably generated (because $\mathbb{R}$ is the codomain of $T$), we can conclude that $\{ P_\theta:\mathfrak{B}_\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}$ admits a countable generated sufficient $\sigma$-algebra.
According to 7.1.7 and 7.5.10 Theorems of "Measure Theory" written by V.I. Bogachev, the $P_\theta$ is a perfect probability measure for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.
Therefore, applying the previous theorem we conclude that $S:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ given by $S(x_1,\cdots,x_n):=(T(x_1),\cdots,T(x_n))=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is minimal sufficient statistic for $\{\bigotimes_{i=1}^n P_\theta:\mathfrak{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\to \mathbb{R}\}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}$.
However, using the Neyman-Fisher Factorization Theorem, we can conclude that $R:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $R(x_1,\cdots,x_n):=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $\{\bigotimes_{i=1}^n P_\theta:\mathfrak{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\to \mathbb{R}\}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}$.
With the previous results we arrive at a contraction, as you can see in the question I mentioned before.
My question is: Did I make a mistake earlier or were the conditions of that theorem correctly met? Does anyone have any idea where the mistake is in those papers?

You have made an error in interpreting those papers. The product family is not $\{\bigotimes_{i=1}^n P_\theta\}_{\theta \in \Theta}$, it is $\{P_{\theta_1} \otimes \dots \otimes P_{\theta_n}\}_{(\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n) \in \Theta^n}$.
The statistic $S$ is minimal sufficient for the latter family, whereas $R$ is minimal sufficient for the (much smaller) former family.

Thank you very much! Just to add something: it's $R$ instead of $T$.
